# How feasible is a daemon written in PHP, using ignore_user abort and set_time_limit(0)

Tags: php, daemon

I'm mucking about with daemons, and wondered how feasible (in terms of memory and cpu usage, and reliability) it is to do this using PHP:

```
<?php
// Ignore user aborts and allow the script
// to run forever
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$fp = fopen('loop.log', 'w');
fwrite($fp, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' Started' . PHP_EOL);
while(1) {
    fwrite($fp, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' Looped' . PHP_EOL);
    if (file_exists('loop.stop')) {
        break;
    }
    // Sleep for 100 seconds
    sleep(100);
}
fwrite($fp, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' Stopped' . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
```

This simple example (adapted from the PHP manual for [ignore_user_abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)) is just the container script. The actual functionality will be placed inside the `while` loop.

I've got this script running on my laptop for 7 hours now, and it looks fine, but it doesn't do much. Has anyone else tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend to put the loop into a BASH script, so that any PHP resources are regularly cleaned up.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
date

php -f doChecksAndAct.php
sleep 100
# rerun myself
exec $0
```

If you were doing any particularly heavy-to-setup tasks in the PHP script, you could also put a small(ish) loop in there (say 50-100 iterations, if they were not pausing multiple seconds between them) to reduce the total overhead time between runs.

**Addition:** I've blogged on a Bash/PHP (or other language) pairing so that you can very easily loop in the PHP script, then exit to restart immediately, or pause for a while - [Doing the work elsewhere -- Sidebar running the worker](http://www.phpscaling.com/2009/06/23/doing-the-work-elsewhere-sidebar-running-the-worker/).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against it.

There is a bug open 4 years ago which says [Memory allocated for objects created in object methods is not released](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33487).

The devs consider this a *Feature request* but it's very hard to work around it when using long-running processes. I tried to but was extremely relieved when I was able to retire the application.

Answer (score 0):

sonic server daemon might be worth checking out aswell

http://dev.pedemont.com/sonic